# How to convert GMT time to string time

Tags: python, datetime, time, gmt

How to convert GMT time to string time? it's quite strange, when I print the time in back-end, the time is in string time format, but when I transfer it to the front-end via JSON file, the time has changed to GMT format. Why? Could someone help me?

```
Input: Wed, 25 Jul 2018 19:19:42 GMT

Output: 2018-07-25 19:19:42
```

Comment: Tip: Look at strptime and strftime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert the original time to JSON Format, it will be changed to GMT Time format. To solve this problem, you can change the time to string before converting it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like -

```
from datetime import datetime
ip = 'Wed, 25 Jul 2018 19:19:42 GMT'
op = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(ip,'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# op 2018-07-25 19:19:42
```

Refer to this beautiful table [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to get the formats right and then look into `strftime` and `strptime`

Answer (score 0):

You can find resources here on [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
from datetime import datetime
t = 'Wed, 25 Jul 2018 19:19:42 GMT'
datetime.strptime(t,'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 25, 19, 19, 42)
```

Comment: You may want to change the third line to `datetime.strptime(t,'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')` to parse the time zone name.